# How to detect day light saving and convert to BST (local time) in moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am working on a project and suddenly found an issue. Issue was, server is sending Unix timestamps which is GMT but due to daylight saving the date
was populated as GMT. It can be achievable from server end but there is very simple way where we can convert it to local-time zone(in my case GMT to BST)

Create three variables

1. getPerfectLocalTime
2. yourUnixTimestamp
3. yourFormat

And below is the logic, you can use

```js
var GMTtime  = moment(yourUnixTimestamp*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // It should be YYYY-MM-DD format
var convertToUtc = moment.utc(GMTtime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var localTimeToDate  = moment.utc(convertToUtc).toDate();

var isDSTDateTime = moment(GMTtime, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
var month = isDSTTime.format('M');
var day   = isDSTTime.format('D');
var year  = isDSTTime.format('YYYY');
if(moment([year, month, day]).isDST()){
 getPerfectLocalTime = moment(localTimeToDate).format(yourFormat);
}else {
 getPerfectLocalTime = moment(yourUnixTimestamp*1000).format(yourFormat);
}
```

Hope it helps anyone in programming world :)

Comment: Is there a question here?  I can simplify your code considerably, if that's what your asking for..

Comment: And actually, the calculation is wrong here.  In general, when you find yourself jumping through parsing and formatting hoops, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your response. This is not a question actually. This is just a post which can help somebody who want to use it. Sorry to say, it is working perfect for me. It would be great, if you can tell me where it is wrong so that I can rectify it. Thanks

Comment: You should follow the guidelines in [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: The main reason your calculation is wrong is because you're not accounting for months being 0-11 in the array passed to the moment constructor.  You're also assuming that you should use local time for DST and UTC for standard time, but that is completely wrong - it only works for London because BST is +1.  It will fail in other time zones.  Also this is just way overkill for the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the only input in your example is `yourUnixTimestamp`, and you are multiplying by 1000, I'll assume that this is a traditional Unix Timestamp - an integer number in terms of whole seconds since midnight 1970-01-01 UTC.

Simply call `moment.unix` to parse this particular kind of input value.  The resulting `moment` object will already be in local mode, so you can just format it directly.

```
moment.unix(yourUnixTimestamp).format(yourFormat)
```

If you want to know whether or not DST is in effect in the local time zone, you can just ask for that directly too.

```
moment.unix(yourUnixTimestamp).isDST()
```

But note that you do not need to know this to format the time correctly.  Moment already takes this into consideration internally.